# To restrict a node from `tree` by Tree or Git

Tags: unix, command-line, tree

**How can you restrict a node from the command `tree`?**

## #1

I need to give a tree of my project files reqularly for my supervisor.
These files contain some third-party components which I do not want to show in the tree.
I have solved this problem this far by coping the project file to tmp, removing 3rd party-files and then running `tree`.

However, this procedure is becoming cumbersome.
I would like to get a better way to give tree of my files to my supervisor.

## #2

I have the files which I want to show in Git so Git may solve this problem.
I run unsuccessfully

```
 git ls-files --with-tree
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the files you want to match and avoid using general patterns. From the `tree` [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree):

> -P pattern
>       List only those files that match the wild-card pattern. Note: you must use the -a option to also consider those files beginning with a dot '.' for matching. Valid wildcard operators are '*' (any zero or more characters), '?' (any single character), '[...]' (any single character listed between brackets (optional - (dash) for character range may be used: ex: [A-Z]), and '[^...]' (any single character not listed in brackets) and '|' separates alternate patterns.
>
> -I pattern
>       Do not list those files that match the wild-card pattern.

In your specific case, running

```
tree -I '3rd*'
```

should hide a directory called '3rd_party', including subdirs and files, while still allowing matches like 'party_3rd'. Obviously, other files and directories not containing '3rd' in the name will also display as normal. I've verified this behaviour with tree v1.5.2.1 on Linux.

Comment: This does not seem to be enough, since I would like to have a tree of files which match the following `pseudo-code`: **tree ^3rd**. That is match everything else than files or folders starting with 3rd.

Comment: This works for me: tree -I '3rd*'. It doesn't display a dir called "3rd_party", but does display "party_3rd" and other files. Seems to do exactly what you want...

Answer (score 0):

You can put the third party tools is a separate subdirectory.

Then you only have to eliminate one node.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the `tree` command it might be better to place the 3rd-party files in a sibling folder of, not in a child folder of, your own source.